# pyautogui.locateOnScreen and pyautogui.position gives different results

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I am using pyautogui 0.9.53 version with python 3.7.8.

When I try to locate an image using:

```
pyautogui.locateOnScreen(img_path)
```

I get the result:

`Box(left=538, top=701, width=718, height=1280)`

but when I put my cursor on the top left of the image on screen, and use the command:

```
pyautogui.position()
```

I get the result:

`Point(x=271, y=354)`

and on the bottom right:

`Point(x=624, y=987)`

How is it possible?

It looks like `pyautogui` mouse and screen does not use the same coordinates.

To make it more clear, if I execute the command:

```
pyautogui.moveTo(pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(img_path))
```

Then the cursor is set to the end of the screen

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here:
https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/735

Apparently, the retina screen on mac os is multiplying the pixels by 2.
The solution is to divide the result by 2